# Throwing an HttpResponseException always results in a StatusCode: 500 response in the client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, http-headers

I'm writing an MSMVC API to handle simple user registration.  In the API I want to throw exceptions when the data passed to the controller is invalid.

```
    public XmlResult RegisterByEmailAddress(UserModel model)
    {
        var errorResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Problem"),
            ReasonPhrase = "Problem"
        };
        throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
    }
```

However regardless of what I set in the exception I only ever see a 500 error in the client response.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and running the API in debug mode on the local IIS server.

The actual content of the response as seen in the Chrome Dev is :

Method : Get, Status : 500 Internal Server Error, Type text/html

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Looks like the code you've got there is okay (though you should be passing the `errorResponse` object to the exception. Does that code get hit in debug? Maybe post more of your controller code? And/or any more info from the response?

Comment: Is this error handled in ExceptionFilterAttribute? After adding the error to the ResponseMessage why are you rethrowing the error?

Comment: @SimonC - I've updated the code to show the whole controller.  I'm basically throwing the exception every time just to test.

Comment: @Nilesh - I'm not handling the exception in a filter, I believe the HttpResponse exception is handled by the framework?

Comment: @RichardAdams I think you need to be using post for that method, or decorate it with an `[HttpGet]` attribute. But that isn't the problem (or it would return a 405). Think you will need to post your request and your routes as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, based on your own answer, and some tests I just did, that your controller is inheriting from the wrong base class. If you posted the rest of the controller it might be easier to see.

All API controllers should inherit from ApiController

```
MyController : ApiController
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, well after much trial and error the following works :

```
throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid password provided to the Api");
```

This seems to go against the documentation which (I think) recommends throwing an HttpResponseException when developing an Api.

Comment: This may not be the way to go but unless anyone can explain why this it's wrong I'll go ahead and accept my own answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar but in the extended ExceptionFilterAttribute. Not sure if you can do that but thought of sharing the code I currently use. This is just a sample. as I have lot more to add in this method.

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    var actionName = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
    var controllerName =
        actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
    Logger.LogException(controllerName + ":" + actionName, actionExecutedContext.Exception);
    actionExecutedContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                                         {
                                             ReasonPhrase = YourPhrase
                                         };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inheriting ApiController and throwing HttpException in the constructor - you will get Internal Server error (500), regardless what HttpStatusCode you passed

Answer (score 0):

If you throw the exception from the constructor or a function/method called from the constructor, it will also give your status 500.